# How do I transform a file to .txt file using pandas?

Tags: machine-learning, pandas

I have to submit a machine learning project, and it has to be node in a .txt file. I know that if I am using pandas, and I want to transform a file from another format to .csv format I can use .to_csv().

Is there something similar for transforming the file into .txt() file using pandas?

Comment: Check this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.to_csv()` as you might know is part of pandas owned IO-API (InputOutput API).
Currently panas is providing 18 different formats in this context.
And of course pandas is also able to write txt-files. With other words pandas is a multi data converter:
[Pandas IO tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html)

To do so with pandas use to_csv with the sep='\t' attribute:

`df.to_csv('data.txt', sep='\t')`

The next option you have to do it with numpy in that way, which is a bit laborious:

1. Call `pd.DataFrame.to_numpy()` to convert a `pd.DataFrame` to a NumPy array
2. Use `np.savetxt(fname, X, fmt = "%s")` with the string "%d" as fmt and the NumPy array as X to write the contents of X into the file fname.